# iOS vs OS X development, and our identity as a company

Tags: ios, macos, code-signing-certificate

We have an iOS product that has been on the Store for a few years.

At this time, we are about to launch another software that targets the Mac OS platform.

So - two distinct products, with two different teams (well, I'm a "one man team" on the Mac OS side) working on them.

We are not yet sure whether we would want to distribute the app via Mac App Store or not. I understand that depending on the option, we will need different certificates to sign the product.

My question is: since we are the same company, do I somehow need to "hook" the new account with the one we have on iOS, in order to maintain the same...identity of the Co.? Hope it makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer - the Team Agent should manage the process. More details: [in Apple's docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ManagingYourTeam/ManagingYourTeam.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH16-SW10).